# How to read a CSV file using shell script at granular level?

Tags: shell, csv

My sample CSV file is:

```
test1,a=1,b=2  
test2,c=3,d=4
```

I can get fields test1 a=1 b=2 using

```
while read f1 f2 f3  
do
    echo $f1  
    echo $f2  
    echo $f3  
done < filename.csv
```

but I want to read `a=1` separately and save `a` in param1 and `1` in param2. I want to do this for all the f2 & f3 one by one.

Could anyone help me in this?

Comment: Can you please format your code using four spaces at the start of the line or backticks around inline code? Further it's not clear if you want to extract the other fields too as your're only talking about `a`. It would be nice if you'd add the code you have so far and comment what's wrong. You should know that it's hard to give one answer since one could give multiple depending on your question.

Comment: That is not a CSV file: it contains no commas.

Comment: What are you going to do with the values when you have them, as `awk` is probably better...

Comment: in another text file i have a fields Eg. a=10, b=12 , c=13and i want to replace those values in text file with the values in csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the IFS to be comma or equals, like this:

```
while IFS=",=" read a b c d e
do 
   echo $a
   echo $b
   echo $c
   echo $d
   echo $e
done < file
```

**Output**

```
test1
a 
1 
b
2
test2
c
3 
d
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. Now in target file i have line like a="11" b="22"
i want to search in target file for a and replace its value by 1.
so my target file will be now a="1" b="22"

How can i do that? i am very confused.

Comment: Edit your question and show us how your target file looks please. Also, please explain what the fields "test1" and "test2" are for.